# What is the origin of the capacitance formula?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, history, formula-derivation

Everyone knows capacitance is defined as C = Q/V, but why? Sure I understand the utility of it and its use, but can someone provide a motivation or historical context for this definition? I'm unable to find one on the internet. What I am is asking is if someone can tell me who came up with this definition? When did they do so? What problem were they confronted with? etc...

Comment: Have you check any Wikipedia articles on the subject? Which textbook did you manage to digest before arriving to this question?

Comment: Yeah I checked out the wikipedia capacitor and capacitance articles but no history really, just explanation of theory. I was actually reading Paul Nahin's book on the history of i ( or j, whatever you want to call it) when I thought of this question. Great book by the way highly recommend it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the township of *Leyden*, glass jars were discovered in the 15th century to hold a charge between metal plates, the term **"Charge Accumulators"** became popular with friction generations creating the charges. Then when **Coulomb** and later **Faraday** found materials with higher superficial charge density, due to a higher dielectric constant they became known as **"*Condensers"***. Now the d constant is so diverse for many reasons, we just call them "**CAPACITORs**".  I would like to talk about the historical significance of Q=CV with some personal experience.

200 Years ago there were many brilliant Mathematicians **Laplace, Poisson, Green, Gauss, Ohm, Heaviside** that described many characteristics of Voltage and Current using the force or motion on particles  yet none of them adopted **Faraday's** *** intuition*** ( see graph at end) and the 18th century mathematicians above insisted it was a surface **Force at a distance** between conductors.
 I won't. but,  **Maxwell proved they were both correct.** You can read his books.

- I recall in the early 70's at university I was taught nothing about dielectric properties of materials, until I read a  Mil-Std Hdbk on capacitor properties after I graduated and got my first job in an Aerospace R&D dept. It was then, that I discovered that Carl Jung "aha" experience on the difference between mica, tantalum , teflon , alum. electrolytic, polyester, polyurethane, polystryrene, and all the other capacitor materials.
- Did you know why  Tesla's Mica insulation made the best hi9gh voltage? It was the best because he knew that he needed it to be > 99.99% pure.

  - That purity may have improved by now in terms of parts per milion or even billion (ppb) and that "purity" is the most critical property in all dielectrics including semiconductors for defect size in 450mm wafers and in batteries for lowest ESR, highest Ah capacity and self-leakage as well the tetrahedral tolerances of atom bond angles in Lithium Phosphate (LiPo) battery molecules and passivization chemicals that prevent self discharge.

  ### - That impurity is also what leads to premature power transformer explosions.

**Faraday** wrote many books *( you can find and read)* on the lab experiments properties of materials for Q=CV where he saw the forces in between particles while the *Math guys* all saw voltage as a force or motion from a distance between conductors.  Both were correct as **Maxwell** discovered and he put it all together.   "Holtz" also experimented in ionization and showed quantity of electricity in each discharge is independent of the strength
of the current and of the material of the electrodes, and that it depends on the nature and density of the gas, and on the distance and form of the
electrodes. He verified Faraday's discovery that the breakdown of a medium at a conductor surface was a little less when it was negative than when it is
positive.  This meant electrons were -ve and more easily escaped orbit in conductors.  In essence **Maxwell** proved **all insulators are dielectrics and everything else is a conductor** and explained in math how all the prior discoveries before and during this century including Newton's Laws, Faraday's Laws, Gauss's Laws, Lenz's Law, Ohm's Law were unified in what we now call Maxwell's Laws.

Yet Faraday still had some "[paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox)" that he could not solve like linked flux does not change yet an emf is induced and meanwhile **Lenz** accurately describe the EMF being generated from motion.  It was **Maxwell** who explained how they cancel each other out in a motor.

Not only is it important to realize that Ic=C*dV/dt but it is actually \$Ic=CdV/dt + VdC/dt\$.  **Faraday**'s experiments showed this even though he did not do the math.  Those who know about some ceramic properties may understand this significance.

- I recall verifying myself in the early 80's when I was implementing ESD awareness at a large Burrough's plant in Winnipeg for large Disk Drives (HDD) and Computer systems as TE Mgr with all the best test gear. I could measure my body voltage with a little LED box and metal touch pad. First I would ground myself measure 0V then slowly raise one foot and touch measured 200V, returned my foot to the insulated ground and got near 0V again. Why? because I was changing my body shape and thus V=Q/C and while Q was constant, I changed by body voltage by changing C.  ( Keep this in mind the next time you touch an LED rated for -5V, which is more robust than a 1pF FET rated for 25V.

  **Richard Feynman** commented:

  > "From a long view of the history of the world—seen from, say, ten
  >   thousand years from now—there can be little doubt that the **most
  >   significant event of the 19th century** will be judged as **Maxwell's**
  >   **discovery of the laws of electromagnetism**. The American Civil War will
  >   pale into provincial insignificance in comparison with this important
  >   scientific event of the same decade."

[image]

This mathematical expression of Faraday's wisdom is in the appendix of Maxwell's book above when he was a young Professor of experimental Physics at Oxford.[image]
The above shows Faraday's vision that differed from all the Mathematicians.
Note that C is defined by the space between the parallel plates and of course the dielectric constant. While the tuba effect is the stray capacitance that affects everything around.  The intuition was in Faraday's books from his experiments where the mathematicians disagreed. yet both agreed **Q=CV** . Often today Engineers think of Caps as fixed components but they aren't and piezo ceramics are perfect example.

---

Thus remember that  \$ \frac{dQ}{dt}=  I_C(t) = C\frac {dV}{dt}+V\frac{dC}{dt}\$  is just as important than Q=CV

[**This**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0yJ3blaI7b8C&pg=PA72&dq=farad&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmyajXk77QAhUD24MKHXX6D9wQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=farad&f=false) may give some insights for you on the practical use of Q=CV [**Electronics For Dummies**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0yJ3blaI7b8C&pg=PA72&dq=farad&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmyajXk77QAhUD24MKHXX6D9wQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=farad&f=false)

Answer (score 6):

It all comes down to Maxwell's equations. For a parallel plate capacitor we have:
$$\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{A} = \frac{q}{\varepsilon_0}$$
Where \$\mathbf{A}\$ is the normal surface area vector to the plates, i.e. we construct our area of integration to cover the plates.
For a capacitor it is assumed that the field is uniform i.e. it does not vary on the plates, like this:
[image: cap]
The integral becomes simple multiplication:
$$E A = \frac{q}{\varepsilon_0}$$
We can now use the definition for voltage, and substitute the constant electric field:
$$V = - \int \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = E l$$
Where \$\mathbf{l}\$ is the vector from one plate to the other, following the field lines in the figure above.

You can substitute to get:
$$V\frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{l} = q$$

We can simply define the constant part as the capacitance: $$C = \frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{l}$$

That is why you get the equation \$Q = CV\$. It is just a constant term that appears in the equations.

It is important to note that the above line of reasoning is only valid when the assumptions hold. The electric field is not constant in reality. The field lines do something like this:
[image: real cap]
Also, this analysis is valid only for electrostatics. As soon as you get a magnetic field, it starts influencing the electric field, violating the assumptions. Here is the accuracy of the capacitance for a parallel plate:
[image: accuracy]

Comment: Very nice answer. But it would be better if you pointed out that \$\mathbf{A}\$ is surface area vector of the plates and \$\mathbf{l}\$ is the direction vector. Don't misunderstand, just for the OP to understand clearly.

Comment: @RohatKılıç good point, I edited my answer.

Comment: Faraday new Q=CV long before Maxwell

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That may be so. My answer outlines the motivation between the definition of capacitance. It also gives the assumptions needed to ensure a linear relationship in \$Q=CV\$. In fact in real systems the capacitance is not constant. Also, as we have a better understanding of the physical world since Faraday, we can show why certain things are true. There is a difference between knowing that something is true, and knowing why it is true.

Comment: and then predicting and verifying it is true by experiment was Faraday's wisdom where Maxwell applied the math to his lines of force which during his time with Gauss etc had  no equation. But in more precise terms.  we often forget \$ \frac{dQ}{dt}= Ic(t) = C\frac {dV}{dt}+V\frac{dC}{dt}\$

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Well, the theoreticians didn't have their basics right. Later on when ideas from abstract algebra, and topology were incorporated into differential geometry we understood that forces were actually dual vectors. They had to start from the beginning a couple of times because mathematicians tried to apply common sense, and got paradoxical results. Once they axiomatized algebra, things started to work out. Besides, I don't like explanations that solely rely on experimentation. By all means measure things, but ensure that you understand why you are getting a certain result.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 good point about the derivative of Q when C is not constant. This is especially important in semiconductors e.g. PV cells.

Comment: also important in XR7 ceramic caps which drop C with rising Vdc and also microphonics in ceramics and changing d with frequency in PCB dielectric for step response, nanotube properties of graphene batteries , the "double layer effect" in ultracaps, and the Partial Discharge effects in megawatt transformers

Comment: @user110971 by theoreticians are you including Laplace, Poisson, Green, Gauss, Ohm, and Heaviside, whom I was referring to that were contrary to Faraday's book "Research" with path of forces in a dielectric

Answer (score 4):

> capacitance is defined as C = Q/V, but why?

Because this is the DEFINITION of capacitance, as a measure of ability of a system of isolated conductors (with dielectric in between) to store an electric charge Q with resulting potential V. Capacitance is a property of particular geometry of conductors. Historically it was found that the **ratio of charge Q to resulting voltage V** for a given conductor geometry (like parallel plates) was a constant, which is called "capacitance". This feature was found in [experiments with Leyden Jars](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/capacitor3.htm) in mid-1700.

Comment: yet   \$Ic(t)=C\frac {dV}{dt}+V\frac{dC}{dt}\$  and \$I(t)=\frac{dQ}{dt}\$ or ~~ \$ \frac{dQ}{dt}=C\frac {dV}{dt}+V\frac{dC}{dt}\$  is more important than Q=CV

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, these equations describe dynamics of charge flows. They do not repeal the **fundamental fact** the C is a prominent and well defined feature of a static configuration of conductors. dC/dt = 0 in most practical cases, except in paracitics in semiconductors, where an interplay of conductive boundaries with electrical fields can be considered as variable conductor geometry forming a "variable capacitor"

Comment: but it neglects the critical properties of 
 
also important characteristics in XR7 ceramic caps which drop C with rising Vdc and also microphonics in ceramics and changing d with frequency in PCB dielectric for step response, nanotube properties of graphene batteries , the "double layer effect" in ultracaps, and the Partial Discharge effects in the dielectrics of mega/gigawatt transformers to list a few... more relevant is who was the first to recognise Q=CV

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, ok, ok, you won, there are more areas with variable capacitance. However, all effects you list are coming form VARIABLE CONFIGURATION of conductive surfaces, effectively. Therefore they constitute a different class of objects, variable objects. My interpretation (C being a measure of fixed configuration of conductors) is still a primary definition, historically.

Answer (score 0):

Take a capacitor where you can adjust e.g. the plate distance. Load it with a defined charge at a defined voltage. Then disconnect it from the source and increase the plate distance. From the mechanical change, you can calculate capacitance decreased with 1/d.

But voltage increased by the reciprocal factor. And that's why we see U = Q / C.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply

$$i = C \frac{dV}{dt}$$

Integrate both sides with respect to time and note \$ Q = \int i \text{ }dt\$ and we get

$$Q = \int i \text{ }dt = C \cdot V \Rightarrow C = \frac{Q}{V}$$

Comment: you forgot about \$+V\frac{dC}{dt}\$

Comment: I was assuming capacitance does not change.

Comment: it would improve your answer to state assumptions that are often important attributes  in nature of materials that are often not true.